# Is there a way to specify max crawl depth when using the Apify SDK?

Tags: web-crawler, apify

I'm working on a project for which I'm evaluating both Scrapy and Apify. Most of the code centers around node.js so a javascript solution would be nice. Also, I like the fact that I can use puppeteer in Apify. That said, my use-case requires doing fairly shallow (e.g. depth of roughly 4) crawls of many web sites. This is easy to configure in Scrapy, but I can't figure out how to do it in Apify. Is there a way to specify max depth in the new Apify API? It looks like this was a parameter in their legacy crawler, but I haven't found it in the new API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches you can take. Firstly, you can use the [Puppeteer Scraper](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apify/) public actor, which enables you to use most of Apify SDK's features in a simplified form and the **max crawl depth configuration** is available there as a simple input under the **Performance and limits** section. To learn the basics, [visit the introduction tutorial](https://apify.com/docs/scraping/tutorial/introduction).

The second approach is more involved and uses the Apify SDK directly. With all your requests, you can pass arbitrary user data down using the `request.userData` property. This way, before you add more pages to the crawling queue, you can check if you'd not reached the desired depth:

```js
const MAX_DEPTH = 4;

// When creating the request queue, we seed the first request with a depth of 0.
const requestQueue = await Apify.openRequestQueue();
await requestQueue.addRequest({
 url: "https://stackoverflow.com",
 userData: {
   depth: 0,
 }
});

// ...

// Then, somewhere in handlePageFunction, when adding more requests to the queue.
if (request.userData.depth < MAX_DEPTH) {
  await requestQueue.addRequest({
    url: "https://example.com",
    userData: {
      depth: request.userData.depth + 1,
  }
});

}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is what I suspected. I will go with the userData approach. Thanks for including a code example. I'd upvote this but I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

You can find options "Max crawling depth" in [apify/web-scraper](https://apify.com/apify/web-scraper?section=input-schema). This tool is a replacement for a legacy phantomJS scraper. It uses puppeteer and it has a very similar interface.

You can even use [Apify SDK](https://sdk.apify.com/) and implement max depth on your own using PuppeteerCrawler. I recommend using request.userData to log how deep you are in crawling. If you are interested in this solution you can check [the source code of web scraper](https://github.com/apifytech/actor-scraper/blob/master/web-scraper/src/crawler_setup.js#L377), how it is done in web-scraper.

Comment: Thanks. That confirms it for me. Just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Unfortunately, I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation :-(